# How use tojson in pre-registered mushache template in Elasticsearch

Tags: templates, elasticsearch, mustache

How use terms in pre-registered mushache template in Elasticsearch

Hi,

I use the Elasticsearch v5.6.3. In the kibana Console, I attempt to save a search template with a term query.

```
POST _scripts/test-json
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": {"query": {"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"terms": {"beat.hostname": {{#tojson}}hostname{{/tojson}} } }] } } } }
  }
}
```

But I got a syntax error without the double quote.

I saw the issue in github.
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/21648

I changed the template like the sample in this issue, it's no syntax error. But I can not get the result.

```
POST _scripts/test-json
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": {"query": {"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"terms": {"beat.hostname": ["{{hostname}}"] } }] } } } }
  }
}
```

And then I changed the template:

```
POST _scripts/test-json
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": {"query": {"filter": {"bool": {"must": [{"terms": {"beat.hostname": ["{{#tojson}}hostname{{/tojson}}}}"] } }] } } } }
  }
}
```

After call is, I got a runtime error.

```
  {
    "type": "json_parse_exception",
    "reason": "Unexpected character ('h' (code 104)): was expecting comma to separate Array entries\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.bytes.BytesReference$MarkSupportingStreamInputWrapper@396f6738; line: 1, column: 190]"
  }
```

How could I send some params for the terms in a pre-registered search template?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is resolved. The key is the script.source can be a string which contain the query JSON.

```
POST _scripts/test-json
{
  "script": {
    "lang": "mustache",
    "source": "{\"size\": 0, \"query\": {\"bool\": {\"must\": [{\"terms\": {\"beat.hostname\": {{#tojson}}hostname{{/tojson}} } } ] }}}"
  }
}
```

This script can be saved success. And then call it like below:

```
GET _search/template
{
  "id": "test-json",
  "params": {
    "hostname": ["host-1", "host-2"]
  }
}
```

Hard to find the solution :-)

Comment: Don't know if it fits here, but anyway... How can I POST a custom script? How do I source it if I installed it in my machine via bin/elasticsearch-plugin install <my-plugin>. How can I reference it to play with it in elasticsearch?